# 404 accessing SharePoint site from internet by IP address

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site which I can access locally as follows.

```
http://spdevsite/sites/dev/
```

However, when I try to access this site from internet as follows

```
http://IP_ADDRESS/sites/dev (where IP_ADDRESS is the IP address)
```

I get asked to login and then get redirected to

```
http://IP_ADDRESS/sites/dev/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

which displays 404 NOT FOUND error.

How could I fix this problem? It seems that the SP server was reached since I got asked to login, but something went wrong afterwards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem, in `Alternate Access Mappings` > `Edit Public URLs` I added `http://IP_ADDRESS` in the **Internet** text field.

Comment: Thanks, For detailed process please refer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx